# Team Foundation Server TFSConfig recover

Tags: configuration, database-backups, database-restore

When trying to restore my backuped TFSCollection via Administration Console (attach collection) the attachment fails. (NullReference Exception)

Are there any problems when restoring collections without the original configuration database?

The Collections is listed, but state doesn`t change from "offline", even when i tried to re-run the job.

When looking into [TFSCollection].[tbl_projects] via Management Studio I can see all projects.

When trying to restore the collection via

```
TFSConfig RegisterDB /sqlInstance:DataCenter\MSSQLServer /databaseName:DataCenter\MSSQLServer;Tfs_Configuration
```

I get the following error:

> The following exception was caught while trying to validate the database: Keyword not supported: 'tfs_configuration;integrated security'.

Or when i run:

```
TFSConfig recover /ConfigurationDB:DataCenter\MSSQLServer;Tfs_Configuration /CollectionDB:DataCenter\MSSQLServer;Tfs_TFSCollection
```

The following error occurs:

> TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that
>   the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problem
>   s are not blocking communication with the server.

Maybe I´ve run into some serious problem when installing TFS Service Pack 1.

What could i do to restore my TFS?

Even the import in my virtual enviroment fails. See the [logfile](http://pastebin.ca/2133549).

Comment: Did you try SQL restore feature that comes with the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone had the same problem, take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2516423.

If you cant access your collections you could try.

```
TfsConfig updates /reapply
```

To start the TFS Job Agent you can run.

```
TfsServiceControl unquiesce
```

Or if the "Serviving" State doesnt change you could try this.

```
TfsConfig diagnose /scope:updates
TfsConfig updates /reapply
```

Hope this could help..